# Objects not found when reading in a function via R Studio

Tags: r, syntax-error, curly-braces

When I run my code via R-Studio I'm told I have an unexpected curly brace.

I have four: two to open/close the function and two for the for loop. I'm then told many of the variables are not found: Unexpected "for", "directory" not found, "basedf" not found. It's as if nothing from my function is recognized.

I tried cutting and pasting the function directly into the console but with similar errors.

Is my function flawed, or is something else the issue?

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
    files <- list.files(directory)
    subsetFiles <- files[id]
    basedf <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(character(),
            sulfate = numeric(),
            nitrate = numeric(),
            ID = numeric())
    for (i in subsetFiles) {
        filepaths <- paste(directory,"/",i, sep='')
        basedf <- rbind(basedf, read.csv(filepaths))
    }
    good <- complete.cases(basedf)
    data2 <- basedf[good,pollutant]
    mean(data2)
}
```

Comment: You could save a few steps with `list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)`.  And you need a few `[i]`s in there I think.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RichardScriven. I'm learning to crawl right now though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing a bracket in `basedf`:

```
basedf <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(character(),
                     sulfate = numeric(),
                     nitrate = numeric(),
                     ID = numeric()))
```

Then everything should work fine.

Alternatively, you could have the bracket at the end of as.Date as stated by flamenco, but your function will still compile either way. It depends on what the purpose of your function is.

Comment: Thank you very much accepting when the times comes off. Wonder if there's a way in R to help debug syntax like that, as opposed to the standard error messages which were diverting my attention

Comment: I assume you got the error `Error: unexpected 'for' in:...` before your unexpected brace error. In my experiences, if you get an `Error: unexpected...` it usually means you are missing a match for a bracket, brace, quote, etc.

Additionally, Rstudio has some built in debug tools: http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/debugging/overview, but I'm not sure if they'd help here, since I've never used them

Comment: Thanks again appreciate the pointers and extra eyes on my function

Comment: @ Doug Firr: See the answer bellow for the missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it should be as:

```
          basedf <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(character()),
                                              sulfate = numeric(),
                                              nitrate = numeric(),
                                              ID = numeric())
```

There is missing parenthesis but is the closing one from `as.Date()`.

It seems that you are working on the assignment from Coursera.
You might want to add the `format` for `as.Date()`.

```
 R:> basedf <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(character(), format='%Y/%m/%d'),
                       sulfate = numeric(),
                       nitrate = numeric(),
                       ID = numeric())

 R:> basedf
 [1] Date    sulfate nitrate ID     
 <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```